# How to implement history in typeorm?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to follow after changes in entities with relations.

First of all, I have created 2 entities that have ManyToOne/OneToMany relation between them like:

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  uuid: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;
    
  @OneToMany(() => Item , item => item.user)
  items: Item[];
      
  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2)', select: false })
  updateTime: Date;
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class Item extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  uuid: string;
    
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.items)
  user: User;
  @Column({ select: false })
  userUuid: string;


  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2)', select: false })
  updateTime: Date;
}
```

I'm using [typeorm-revisions](https://github.com/ephillipe/typeorm-revisions) in order to follow after changes, so I add 2 entities to mantain a Revision History like in the docs:

```
@Entity()
export class UserHistory extends User implements HistoryEntityInterface {
  makeActionAt: Date;
  id: string = this.uuid;

  @Column()
  public originalID!: string;

  @HistoryActionColumn()
  public action!: HistoryActionType;
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class ItemHistory extends Item implements HistoryEntityInterface {
  makeActionAt: Date;
  id: string = this.uuid;

  @Column()
  public originalID!: string;

  @HistoryActionColumn()
  public action!: HistoryActionType;
}
```

and also subscribers:

```
@EventSubscriber()
class UserHistorySubscriber extends HistorySubscriber<User, UserHistory> {
  public get entity() {
    return User;
  }
  public get historyEntity() {
    return UserHistory;
  }
}
```

```
@EventSubscriber()
class ItemHistorySubscriber extends HistorySubscriber<Item, ItemHistory> {
  public get entity() {
    return Item;
  }
  public get historyEntity() {
    return ItemHistory;
  }
}
```

Now, when I run `entityManager.save(user)` or `entityManager.save(item)` while user/item can be a new entities or an updated one, it's work correctly - create/update the record inside User/Item accordingly and create a new record inside UserHistory/ItemHistory.

The problems started when I'm trying to get the right entity according to a specific updateTime with the right relation according to the same updateTime. I would like to be able to get the past version of the user with the most updated items according to the updateTime of the user. This is what I tried (not working properly):

```
const query = await this.createQueryBuilder('user')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('user.items', 'item')
        .where('user.uuid= :uuid', { uuid });
        .where('user.updateTime= :updateTime', { updateTime });

// I use getMany() because in my real scenario the query is more complicated then this
return await query.getMany();
```

So, for ex. at some point the DB looks like this:

- user:

| uuid | name | updateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | bob | 2021-6-21 |

- userHistory:

| uuid | name | updateTime | originalID | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 364 | bob | 2021-6-21 | 123 | UPDATED |
| 789 | Alvin | 2021-6-17 | 123 | CREATED |

- item:

| uuid | name | userUuid | updateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 990 | phone | 123 | 2021-6-21 |
| 145 | cup | 123 | 2021-6-20 |

- itemHistory:

| uuid | name | userUuid | updateTime | originalID | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 990 | phone | 123 | 2021-6-21 | 990 | UPDATED |
| 134 | cup | 123 | 2021-6-20 | 145 | UPDATED |
| 2s3 | clock | 123 | 2021-6-19 | 145 | CREATED |
| 3a9 | phone | 123 | 2021-6-16 | 990 | CREATED |

**updateTime is actually a full timestamp but for convenience, I refer to them as dates.**

and I want to do something like this:

```
const uuid = '123', updateTime = '2021-6-17'; // updateTime = '2021-6-18' will be the same
const query = await this.createQueryBuilder('user')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('user.items', 'item')
        .where('user.uuid= :uuid', { uuid });
        .where('user.updateTime= :updateTime', { updateTime });
return await query.getMany();
```

So it will return:

```
User {
  uuid: '123',
  name: 'Alvin'
  items: [
    Item {
      uuid: '990',
      name: 'phone'
    }
  ]
}
```

or with `const uuid = '123', updateTime = '2021-6-21';` So it will return:

```
User {
  uuid: '123',
  name: 'bob'
  items: [
    Item {
      uuid: '990',
      name: 'phone'
    },
    Item {
      uuid: '145',
      name: 'cup'
    }
  ]
}
```

Someone know what's the best way to implement it? thanks ahead!

Comment: were you able to fine something? I am working on doing something similar, and was worries if 'typeorm-revisions' is actively maintained?

Comment: hi @GauravSaluja, any updates on this? :)

Comment: Yes @Jasper, typeorm-revisions packaged worked fine for me. Had to tinker around a little bit, but it go the work done. You can try it out, if you need any help, let me know.